# F# Adding various types to Australian Reserve Bank Type Provider

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-data

I have written a new type provider for Reserve Bank of Australia data files.

Currently all the column data types are strings but I want the first column to be a DateTime and the remaining columns to be Singles. How can I do this?

Here is code for the type provider: https://github.com/stuartjdavies/FSharp.Data.Stats.Aus/blob/master/FSharp.Data.Stats.Aus.TypeProviders/RBACsvStatisticsProvider.fs

Here is a example using the provider: 
https://github.com/stuartjdavies/FSharp.Data.Stats.Aus/blob/master/FSharp.Data.Stats.Aus.Experiments/RBAExchangeRates.fsx

Stuart

Comment: It would be good if you copied the relevant parts of the code to your question.

Comment: This is a nice simple example that shows how to do this kind of thing: https://github.com/simonmahler/TurboCsvFileTypeProvider

Comment: Thanks Tomas that was a clear example. I got it working. It will need a little bit of testing though.